# Extracting predictions from a GAM model with splines and lagged predictors

Tags: r

I have some data and am trying to teach myself about utilize lagged predictors within regression models. I'm currently trying to generate predictions from a generalized additive model that uses splines to smooth the data and contains lags.

Let's say I have the following data and have split the data into training and test samples.

```
head(mtcars)
Train <- sample(1:nrow(mtcars), ceiling(nrow(mtcars)*3/4), replace=FALSE)
```

Great, let's train the gam model on the training set.

```
f_gam <- gam(hp ~ s(qsec, bs="cr") + s(lag(disp, 1), bs="cr"), data=mtcars[Train,])

summary(f_gam)
```

When I go to predict on the holdout sample, I get an error message.

```
f_gam.pred <- predict(f_gam, mtcars[-Train,]); f_gam.pred

Error in ExtractData(object, data, NULL) : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
Calls: predict ... predict.gam -> PredictMat -> Predict.matrix3 -> ExtractData
```

Can anyone help diagnose the issue and help with a solution. I get that `lag(__,1)` leaves a data point as NA and that is likely the reason for the lengths being different. However, I don't have a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using `gam()` from the `mgcv` library. It appears that `gam()` doesn't like functions that are not defined in "base" in the `s()` terms. You can get around this by adding a column which include the transformed variable and then modeling using that variable. For example

```
tmtcars <- transform(mtcars, ldisp=lag(disp,1))
Train <- sample(1:nrow(mtcars), ceiling(nrow(mtcars)*3/4), replace=FALSE)
f_gam <- gam(hp ~ s(qsec, bs="cr") + s(ldisp, bs="cr"), data= tmtcars[Train,])
summary(f_gam)
predict(f_gam, tmtcars[-Train,])
```

works without error.

The problem appears to be coming from the `mgcv:::get.var` function. It tires to decode the terms with something like

```
eval(parse(text = txt), data, enclos = NULL)
```

and because they explicitly set the enclosure to NULL, variable and function names outside of base cannot be resolved. So because `mean()` is in the `base` package, this works

```
eval(parse(text="mean(x)"), data.frame(x=1:4), enclos=NULL)
# [1] 2.5
```

but because `var()` is defined in `stats`, this does not

```
eval(parse(text="var(x)"), data.frame(x=1:4), enclos=NULL)
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "var"
```

and `lag()`, like `var()` is defined in the `stats` package.

Comment: Great explanation as why something doesn't work or throws an error. This helps us, the un-initiated. Thanks @MrFlick!